# Textview under listview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

Hey guys i have an xml in my activity
here's my codes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_corners" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Prices from:" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivprivatecell"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/privatecell" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However, once the listview are loaded i cant see the textview and the imageview at all! what to do ? only the listview's are visible! thanks

Comment: set the height of list view widget 0dp instead of wrap content

Comment: i got an error:
Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, should be used with layout_weight

Comment: @TorrentLookup so what can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `layout_weight` of 1 to each of your ListViews:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_corners" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: "1", as in my example above.

Comment: FD_ I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Answer (score 2):

ListViews are greedy.  They will assume that they need the entire screen in height.  If you want to show things below them, you need to use either a fixed height or a RelativeLayout with items pinned to the bottom of the screen with layouyt_alignParentBottom and the lists forced to layout above them via layout_above

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for you but I would change the parent layout to `RelativeLayout` then attach the `ImageView` to the bottom and put the `TextView` above that and place the two `ListViews` above those using `RelativeLayout` properties.

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_corners"
        android:layout_above="@id/list2" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView1" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Prices from:"
        android:layout_above="@id/ivprivatecell />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivprivatecell"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/privatecell" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Better, add a weight to your layout that contains your listviews and a weight to your textview and your imageview, make sure your weighs are less than 1 and they all sum 1. Finally, put a height of 0dp. With this you can set the % of screen you want each of your views to take on every screen size